# Why is my question downvoted, and why no comment and low views after a while

Tags: support

I have a question about my Arqade post: [What is the sound ID of the Neutron Punch spell in Elemental Battlegrounds on Roblox?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344885/what-is-the-sound-id-of-the-neutron-punch-spell-in-elemental-battlegrounds-on-ro)

Why does no one answer my question for a while? I really need an answer! There are some downvotes, but why? I added detail. Maybe it is too specific. I need help with my question. Please help me.

Comment: You yourself said you don't expect many people to actually *be* able to answer it.  That means it will take time.

Comment: @Frank Makes sense, but that does not explain the low views or the downvotes or lack of comments, that only explains the lack of answers.

Comment: Hi. I managed to find the answer. The id is 392838370

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have an answer because so far no one who has looked at it can answer. Sometiems that happens. I can't speak to why there are downvotes - it could be for a variety of reasons. You haven't told us if you've tried to find the sound ID yourself, or anything like that, you just expect us to do the work for you. Questions here work best if you tell us things you've tried to solve the issue yourself.

As for the low views, Roblox questions just might not be popular here - while we do cover all video games, it varies on what is popular and what the community plays.

Also, it's only been 14 hours - which isn't all that long! It's the weekend, people are busy. Have some patience, I am sure an answer will come in time.

Comment: I have looked for it myself. I have spent hours searching in the sounds list and only found other sounds from the game. I can provide a clip where the sound is played, because all I need is good words to describe the sound so I can search for it.

Comment: I will be most pleased at whoever answers it correctly

Comment: @hankSauri, If you are looking for specific words to describe a sound, I suggest checking out the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Bassie-c ok. Thank you